# Перенос классов из html в scss сохраняя вложенность бэм.Sublime

Tags: html, css, scss, sublime-text, бэм

Работаю в sublime, решил изучить scss. Раньше для переноса классов из HTML в чистый CSS пользовался плагином eCSSstractor и все было ок, работаю по методологии БЭМ.

Есть ли возможность переносить классы из HTML в SCSS так, чтобы сохранялась вложенность?

Чтобы получился похожий результат:

```
.parent {
  &__element{}
}
```

Пока что переносится только так:

```
.parent{}
.element{}
```

Знаю, что в VS code есть подобный функционал, есть ли он в sublime?